# The SkiaSharp runs well in ios simulator but not run in physical device?

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

```
SKCanvasView canvasView=new SKCanvasView();
canvasView.PaintSurface+=CanvasView_PaintSurface;
```

The `CanvasView_PaintSurface` runs well in simulator but not run in physical device.
I googled it and get an answer that `SkiaSharp.Views.iOS.Extensions.IsValidEnvironment` is always false but I do not know why and how to fix it

Comment: Hi , which physical device tested not running ? And you can share the error log here and test with other physical device to check .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I only have one devies iphone X. and where to check the log?

Comment: Hi , there are two ways to check log . First in Visual Studio ,  **View -> Output** to see logs when running project . Second , in **Tools -> iOS -> Device Logs** to check the logs .